# How to get error message from chained MSI in custom bootstrapper?

Tags: c#, wix, burn

If I have a misconfigured MSI (say the XPath on an util:XmlFile element is incorrect) and I run just the MSI, I get a nice descriptive error that says what I did wrong (Could not find element at path X...) before it rolls back the install and goes to the end screen.

If I now run that MSI as part of a custom BA, I lose this error information. I tried the following in the handler for ExecutePackageComplete:

```
string errorMessage = new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()).Message;
```

But that just gave me something about a pipe.

```
string errorMessage = new Win32Exception(e.Status).Message;
```

Gives "A fatal error happened" (or something like that).

I would like to have the full descriptive error message so it is easier to debug failures without having to run the MSI by itself. How do I get that error message in my custom BA?

Answer (score 0):

There is an event on the `BootstrapperApplicaton` object called `Error`. This raises errors for chained MSIs (in addition to other things I'm sure).

The helpful error messages are in the `ErrorMessage` property of its event args:

```
    private void HandleError(object sender, ErrorEventArgs e)
    {
        string errorMessage = e.ErrorMessage;
    }
```

The package that raised the error is in the `PackageId` property as well.